# How would I go about making a tileable or modular object

Tags: texturing, modifiers, obj

Edit: I was not aware the array tool could do this
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html

I would like to make one object that I can extrude and have it continue its design instead of stretching can this be done in blender?

It would also be nice if while doing that it can reduce the poly count

I would like to make the modular parts less bloxy and look more natural, I saw a video that I cant find now where someone was able to resize a building they made and add Floors or extend the length, all simply by changing its size. Was made in blender. It looked like instead of stretching it automatically filled in the space by copying and pasting what was already there. (Copying the first floor and making it a second floor or copying a section and extending the length)

Similar to what I want to create
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/407294360025253499/
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZMTZ.png)!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnFx3.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about using Blender

Comment: I was asking what the easiest method for making assets in blender was, how was that not related to blender???

Comment: Hello and welcome. The way your questions is currently worded reads like a general question about making games. It has nothing to do specifically with Blender which makes it off topic here. It is also highly subjective and any answers would be opinion based which makes not very suited for this site. If you can rephrase it to focus on any specific issue you are encountering with Blender, you can edit the post so we can reopen it.

Comment: hello, do you have some sort of reference image or other source that will help visually describe what it is you are trying to achieve? please add that as another edit, it will help your question be reopened. :)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Hello, the video you saw most likely was using an add-on like **Sverchok** or **Animation Nodes** since as far I know this capability isnt present by default in Blender. But this is already pretty advanced. You should first try to build your library like in the pictures you provided and see what you can build with it. Then you will be able to dive more easily into more sophisticated methods of creating modular assets.

Comment: how do i actually build stuff like what's in the picture though, The snap feature rarely ever works for me, i don't want to build an asset set for use out side of blender i want it for making building inside blender easier.